# How to add edit button and function in react.js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

i want to share this question. So, i have a form which is designed by react-bootstrap. And also use React Hooks and React Function Component. I have a form which is add new form and delete form but i don't do edit form.
This is a return statement

```
return(
        <Container>
            <Row>
                <Col>
                <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <Form.Group>
                        <Form.Label>Name</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control ref = {firstname} type="text" placeholder="Name.." />
                    </Form.Group>
                    <Form.Group>
                        <Form.Label>Surname</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control ref = {secondname} type="text" placeholder="Surname.." />
                    </Form.Group>
                    <Form.Group>
                        <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control ref = {email} type="email" placeholder="E-Mail" />
                        <Form.Text> Please, Enter like "asd@asd.com"</Form.Text>
                    </Form.Group>
                    <Form.Group>
                        <Form.Label>Comment</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control ref = {comment} as="textarea" rows={3} placeholder = "Notes :)"/>
                    </Form.Group>
                    <Button className = "btn-lg" onClick={handleSubmit} variant="success" type="submit">Submit</Button>
                </Form>
                </Col>
            </Row>
            
            {Formss}
        </Container>
    )
```

And then, These are the function of this return

```
const Formss = input.map((item , index) =>
        {
            return(
                <Lists key = {index} item = {item} index = {index} deleteFunc={handleDelete}/>
            )
        }
    )
```

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const name = firstname.current.value
        const surname = secondname.current.value
        const mail = email.current.value
        const mycomment = comment.current.value

        const data = {id:id(),
                    name : name,
                    surname : surname,
                    mail : mail,
                    mycomment : mycomment}
    
        if(data.name && data.surname && data.mail && data.mycomment){
            setInput([...input, data])
            firstname.current.value = ""
            secondname.current.value = ""
            email.current.value = ""
            comment.current.value =""
        }else{
            console.log("oopss")
        }
    }
```

I use ref hook for handleSubmit. So, How to add edit button and edit function?

Comment: So your problem is that you need to be able to edit fields ?

Comment: I want to input data manipulate, For example enter some email name surname and then i want to change these information

Answer (score 0):

To be able to edit data, and to save it in state you can do it as in provided example. Then in `handleSubmit` function you can process your data further:

```
import React from "react";
import { Container, Row, Col, Form, Button } from "react-bootstrap";

const App = () => {
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(state);
  };

  const initialState = {
    firstname: "",
    secondname: "",
    email: "",
    comment: "",
  };

  const [state, setState] = React.useState(initialState);

  const handleChange = ({ target: { value, name } }) => {
    setState({ ...state, [name]: value });
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <Row>
        <Col>
          <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Form.Group>
              <Form.Label>Name</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                name="firstname"
                value={state.firstname}
                type="text"
                placeholder="Name.."
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group>
              <Form.Label>Surname</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                name="secondname"
                value={state.secondname}
                type="text"
                placeholder="Surname.."
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group>
              <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                value={state.email}
                name="email"
                type="email"
                placeholder="E-Mail"
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
              <Form.Text> Please, Enter like "asd@asd.com"</Form.Text>
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group>
              <Form.Label>Comment</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                name="comment"
                value={state.comment}
                as="textarea"
                rows={3}
                placeholder="Notes :)"
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <Button className="btn-lg" variant="success" type="submit">
              Submit
            </Button>
          </Form>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default App;
```